# How do I animate an ellipse to go up and down

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, storyboard

So I'm trying to animate my ellipse to go up and down in a wave type of way.
The thing is I can only make it go forward and down, I'm not sure how I would make it go like a sideway `S`
Like this
[visual representation of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Hlf.png)

This is what I've got so far

```
<Canvas Name="Can1">
            <Ellipse Name="Rect1" Canvas.Left="10" Fill="LightSeaGreen"
                   Stroke="Bisque"
                   StrokeThickness="5"
                   Width="100" Height="100">
                <Ellipse.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="Rect1"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                From="10" To="100"
                                Duration="0:0:2"/>

                                <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="Rect1"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                                From="10" To="100"
                                Duration="0:0:2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Ellipse.Triggers>
            </Ellipse>
        </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an appropriate `EasingFunction` for the vertical animation. Also set `AutoReverse` and `RepeatBehavior`:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="ellipse"
         Fill="LightSeaGreen"
         Stroke="Bisque"
         StrokeThickness="5"
         Width="100" Height="100">
    <Ellipse.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                        From="0" To="1000"
                        Duration="0:0:10"/>

                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                        From="0" To="100"
                        Duration="0:0:1"
                        AutoReverse="True"
                        RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            <SineEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Ellipse.Triggers>
</Ellipse>
```

---

For a more complex movement, create a `PathGeometry` and use it with a `MatrixAnimationUsingPath` to animate the `Matrix` property of a `MatrixTransform` in the `RenderTransform` property of an element.

Comment: Wow! That's amazing! I want to learn more about this, are there any good books or pdfs regarding animations?

Comment: I can recommend WPF *Unleashed* by Adam Nathan. Not sure however how far it goes into animations (can't remember).